# Add a string before

Tags: jquery

i have this code :

```
<span class="regular-price" >
<span class="price">29,90&nbsp;€</span>                                    
</span>
```

This code appears several time in my page html, and i would like to insert a string "Add a string" like this in all those span :

```
<span class="regular-price" >
Add a string
<span class="price">29,90&nbsp;€</span>                                    
</span>
```

Do you have an id how to do?
I have tried it, but it's not working :

```
jQuery("Add a string").insertBefore("#price");
```

Thanks for all

Comment: You could use the `:before` pseudo element and avoid jQuery.

Comment: The word you're looking for is [prepend](https://www.google.com/#q=jquery+prepend)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: Actually, a google search for "jquery add a string before" will give you 3 helpful links in the top 4 results.

Comment: Search documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ before asking these kinds of questions. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows little or no research effort for a trivial issue.

Comment: I have tried this :jQuery("à partir de").insertBefore("#price");

Answer (score 1):

This will do the work:

```
$(function(){
    $("span.regular-price").prepend("Add a string");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4XEQ8/1/)

`$("span.regular-price")` Will select all the `span` elements with `class="regular-price"` and then prepend the text you choose.

Comment: Why down vote? I can understand the op did not try himself but the answer is valid.

Comment: Actually no it's not. You produce output that's different from what the OP wants. Check the console and you'll see.

Comment: Wrong version. Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('Add a string')` attempts to select elements with a structure like

```
<Add><a><string></string></a></Add>
```

Also, `price` is a class, not an `id`. Try

```
jQuery('.price').before('Add a string');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FS3AJ/